# Is it possible to change the file extension of a XML file to CSV using XSLT?

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, export-to-csv

I was able to create a XSLT which transforms the XML file into the format that I want. If I rename the file extension from .xml to .csv, it opens up correctly in Excel. But is there a way that I can create the .csv file directly from the .xslt file itself with the .csv file extension without using another program/code/etc.?

Comment: It depends on which version of XSLT you use and/or how you run your XSLT and which XSLT processor you use. So provide some more details on that and we can hopefully tell your more.

Comment: I'm using v2 for XSLT. The XSLT transformation file is uploaded to the UI, then the processor (not sure which one) in D365 executes a XML file based off of the transformation file.

Comment: XSLT 2 has an `<xsl:result-document href="foo.csv">...</xsl:result-element>` instruction https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees, so that could help if you really use an XSLT 2 processor. How that integrates with D365 I don't know.

Comment: How are you applying the XSLT? If your XSLT generates CSV formatted data, just tell it to write the output of the transform to a file with the *.csv file extension instead of *.xml.

Comment: It's being applied by D365. 



Would this be how you modify the output? I've tried using this snippet, and the browser still spits out a .xml file.  
`<xsl:result-document href="file:C:\\\\foo.csv" format="MainOutput"> `

Comment: As said, you will need to provide the details, I can only show you where to put the `xsl:result-document` if you share a minimal but complete stylesheet you currently have. In general XSLT use URI syntax and the correct syntax for a file URI would be e.g. `href="file:///C:/foo.csv"`.